# VBA inserted HTML image not visible in Outlook by External Parties

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I believe in early 2020 outlook had an update that caused inserted HTML images to not be visible to external parties.

At my old company we had a developer who was able to write something that allowed the image to be visible. I wasn't, and am still not, well versed in coding and have been piecing together stuff, but I can't figure this one out. Not even sure where to start. Any ideas?

If any of the vba below can be cleaned up, please let me know.

```
Sub Email()

'Create and assign email variables
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
'Create and assign JPEF variable
Dim MakeJPG As String
'create and assign workbook variable
Dim wb As Workbook
'create and assign File path variable
Dim Filepath As String
'Create and assign File name variable
Dim Filename As String
'Create and assign File date variable
Dim Filedate As String
'Create and assign Folder Year variable
Dim folderyear As String



With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Filepath = Format(Range("filepath"))
Filename = Format(Range("filename"))
Filedate = Format(Range("trade_date"), "ddmmmyyyy")
folderyear = Format(Range("trade_date"), "yyyy")
```

'========================================================================

'Copy range you want to paste on new worksheet
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Q31").Copy

```
'Open new workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'paste copied range
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Adjust Window Zoom
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80

'Adjust Gridlines
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False

'Adjust Header Row Height
Rows("2:5").Select
Selection.RowHeight = 25.5
Rows("6").Select
Selection.RowHeight = 21

'Adjust DA Sales Column Width
Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 6
Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 12
Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 14
Columns("D:E").ColumnWidth = 10
Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 39
Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 10
Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 16

'Adjust RT Sales Column Width
Columns("I").ColumnWidth = 4
Columns("J").ColumnWidth = 12
Columns("K").ColumnWidth = 14
Columns("L:M").ColumnWidth = 10
Columns("N").ColumnWidth = 39
Columns("O").ColumnWidth = 10
Columns("P").ColumnWidth = 16
Columns("Q").ColumnWidth = 6



'Rename worksheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1"

'Save new worksheet with pasted range
wb.SaveAs Filename:=Filepath & Filename & " " & Filedate & ".xlsx"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Close active workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
```

'========================================================================

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
```

'========================================================================

```
'Create JPG file of the range
'Only enter the Sheet name and the range address
MakeJPG = CopyRangeToJPG("Sheet1", "A1:Q31")



If MakeJPG = "" Then
    MsgBox "Something went wrong, can't create email"
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error Resume Next
```

'========================================================================

```
With OutMail
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "My Company"
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .Display
End With
    Signature = OutMail.HTMLBody
```

'========================================================================

```
'Define & Assign To email list using a named range
Set emailRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("to_email")
For Each cl In emailRng
    sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value
Next
sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)

'Define & Assign CC email list
Set emailRng2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("cc_email")
For Each cl2 In emailRng2
    sCc = sCc & ";" & cl2.Value
Next
sCc = Mid(sCc, 2)
```

'========================================================================

```
With OutMail
    .To = sTo '"Manually enter email address here"
    .cc = sCc '"Manually enter email address here"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Filename & " " & Range("trade_date")
    .Attachments.Add MakeJPG, 1, 0
    'Note: Change the width and height as needed
    .HTMLBody = "<html><p>" & strbody & "</p><img src=""cid:NamePicture.jpg"" width=1150 height=600></html>" & "<br><br>" & Signature & "<br><br>"
    .Attachments.Add Filepath & Filename & " " & Filedate & ".xlsx"
    .Display 'or use .Send
End With
            
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
    



Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

End Sub

'========================================================================

Function CopyRangeToJPG(NameWorksheet As String, RangeAddress As String) As String
Dim PictureRange As Range

```
With ActiveWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).Activate
    Set PictureRange = .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).Range(RangeAddress)
    
    If PictureRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sorry this is not a correct range"
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    PictureRange.CopyPicture
    With .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects.Add(PictureRange.Left, PictureRange.Top, PictureRange.Width, PictureRange.Height)
        .Activate
        .Chart.Paste
        .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "NamePicture.jpg", "JPG"
    End With
    .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects(.Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects.Count).Delete
End With

CopyRangeToJPG = Environ$("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "NamePicture.jpg"
Set PictureRange = Nothing
```

End Function

Comment: Which part can't you figure out, is it `MakeJPG = CopyRangeToJPG("Sheet1", "A1:Q31")` ?

Comment: The image inserts, but it is not viewable to external parties. It isn't an outlook issue, it's the way the image is being inserted and to be honest, I don't entirely understand what the code is doing, I just know I get the result I want for internal parties.

Comment: The jpg is added to the email as an attachment and the htmlbody image tag has a content-id (cid) that matches the filename.'<img src=""cid:NamePicture.jpg""' . I guess Outlook won't open an attachment from an untrusted source. Does it have to be a screenshot or would an html table do instead ?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a screenshot. I'd be willing to do an HTML table, just don't know how.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Create an HTML table from the range rather than an image attachment.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Email()
    
    Const RNG_EMAIL = "A1:Q31"

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim filepath As String, filename As String
    Dim filedate As String, FolderYear As String
    Dim rng As Range, msg As String
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    filepath = Range("filepath")
    filename = Range("filename")
    filedate = Format(Range("trade_date"), "ddmmmyyyy")
    FolderYear = Format(Range("trade_date"), "yyyy")
 
    'Copy range you want to paste on new worksheet
    Set rng = ws.Range(RNG_EMAIL)
    rng.Copy

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' one sheet
    wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, _
                 Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False
    
    FormatSheet wb.Sheets(1)
    With ActiveWindow
        .Zoom = 80
        .DisplayGridlines = False
    End With
    
    'Save new worksheet with pasted range and close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.SaveAs filename:=filepath & filename & " " & filedate & ".xlsx"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    wb.Close False

    ' prepare and send email
    msg = SendEmail(ws, rng)
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation

End Sub

Function SendEmail(ws As Worksheet, rng As Range) As String

    Const CSS = "body{font:12px Verdana};p{font:14px Verdana Bold};"

    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object, cell As Range
    Dim sTo As String, sCc As String
    Dim signature As String, strbody As String

    ' some message text
    strbody = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, " & _
              "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"

     'Define & Assign To email list using a named range
    For Each cell In ws.Range("to_email")
        sTo = sTo & ";" & cell.Value
    Next
    sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)
    
    'Define & Assign CC email list
    For Each cell In ws.Range("cc_email")
        sCc = sCc & ";" & cell.Value
    Next
    sCc = Mid(sCc, 2)

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
     
    With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "My Company"
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .To = sTo
        .cc = sCc
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = Range("filename") & " " & Range("trade_date")
         signature = .HTMLBody
        .HTMLBody = "<html><style>" & CSS & "</style><p>" & strbody & "</p>" & _
                    RngToHtml(rng) & "<br><br>" & signature & "</html>"
        .Display 'or use .Send
    End With
                
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    SendEmail = "Email sent to " & sTo
    
End Function

Function RngToHtml(rng As Range)

    Dim t As String, r As Long, c As Long
    For r = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        t = t & "<tr>"
        For c = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
             t = t & "<td>" & rng.Cells(r, c) & "</td>"
        Next
        t = t & "</tr>" & vbCrLf
    Next
    RngToHtml = "<table width=""1150"">" & t & "</table>"
      
End Function

Sub FormatSheet(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim colWidth, c As Integer
    'DA and RT Sales Column Width A-Q
    colWidth = Array(6, 12, 14, 10, 10, 39, 10, 16, _
                     4, 12, 14, 10, 10, 39, 10, 16, 6)
    With ws
        .Rows("2:5").RowHeight = 25.5
        .Rows("6").RowHeight = 21
        For c = 0 To UBound(colWidth)
            .Columns(c + 1).ColumnWidth = colWidth(c)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you putting that together. I just ran it and that will not work for the customer.

Quick question, what does the Option explicit do for it?

Comment: @Rupare Option Explicit forces you to declare variables with `Dim`. I can't tell from the code if the named ranges like 'filename' are sheet or workbook scoped. They may refer to another sheet 2 for example.

Comment: Understood. They are sheet scoped to allow the users quick modification in the event I'm not available. Thanks for the explanation.